# How do I save ALL generated date to .txt file and not only the last one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, generator

I'm trying to get all the passwords that are generated to be saved to a .txt file. The code below is basically what my code looks like because this is the sample code it was based off of.

```
import random

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456!$%^&*(`)"

while 1:
    password_len = int(input("What length would you like your password to be : "))
    password_count = int(input("How many passwords would you like : "))
    for x in range(0,password_count):
        password  = ""
        for x in range(0,password_len):
            password_char = random.choice(chars)
            password = password + password_char
        print("Here is your password : ", password)
```

This is what I added to have it be saved to a .txt file.

```
    print("\PASSWORDS SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED!\n"  "CHECK THE (generated_passwords.txt) FILE WHERE YOUR (PassGen.exe) IS LOCATED TO VIEW THEM!\n")

    with open('generated_passwords.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(password)
```

But when I run my code it only saves the very last one that was generated and not all of them. How would I fix this? I'm not really sure what to try beyond here because I'm still new to Python so I'm still learning and I haven't seen a solution to my problem anywhere that I've looked.

Im using pyInstaller to turn it into a .exe after the fact as well by the way.

Comment: Why don’t you open the file first, then just after you print each password, you can write it to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code snippet should work for you :)

```py
import random

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456!$%^&*(`)"

while 1:
    password_len = int(input("What length would you like your password to be (0 to exit): "))
    if password_len == 0: print('Thank you :)'); break
    
    password_count = int(input("How many passwords would you like : "))
    
    with open('./stackoverflow/stack14_generated_passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
        for x in range(0,password_count):
            password  = ""
            for x in range(0,password_len):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password = password + password_char
            print("Here is your password : ", password)

            f.write(password + '\n')
    print("\nPASSWORDS SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED!\n"  "CHECK THE (generated_passwords.txt) FILE WHERE YOUR (PassGen.exe) IS LOCATED TO VIEW THEM!\n")
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem! I knew I was on the right path somewhat, I appreciate the help!